# AWS RDS low freeable memory and swap being used

Tags: mysql, memory-leaks, innodb, amazon-rds

I have a t2.medium RDS (4G Memory & MySQL 5.7.22) with the following global variables:

- innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size - 0.125G
- innodb_buffer_pool_instances - 8
- innodb_buffer_pool_size - 3G

And this is the result of **SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;**:

```
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 3298295808
Dictionary memory allocated 1021071
Buffer pool size   196608
Free buffers       8192
Database pages     182510
Old database pages 67208
Modified db pages  46
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 11507859, not young 812666330 1.12 youngs/s, 5324.32 non-youngs/s
Pages read 8720629, created 157094, written 2516637 5.27 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 12.40 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 22 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 182510, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[6344]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
```

The freeable memory is always between 85Mb and 105MB only and around 70MB is being used from the Swap. This is constant even when there are nearly no processes running on RDS.

Can anyone guide me if we need to either update the buffer_pool variables, or if there is any other way to debug this memory issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only 4G of RAM, make `innodb_buffer_pool_size` no bigger than 2G.  This is probably low enough to get rid of the swap problem.

I hope `innodb_buffer_pool_instances - 8G` is a typo.  I would recommend 1 or 2, not thousands, not millions, and certainly not billions.

In general, RDS should have set all the tunables at reasonable values.

**Cron**

Don't use a cron-like mechanism if there is any chance of one iteration not finishing before the next is launched.  Instead, have a continuously-running script (or program) that does a chunk, sleeps for a while, then repeats.  This will (1) finish the task sooner, and (2) not cause a meltdown (or partial meltdown) due to instances stumbling over each other (it *will* happen).

Comment: Thats what I thought also,  that the `innodb_buffer_pool_size ` was too high for a t2.medium but did not want to edit these values without doing some research.  Yes it was a typo : `innodb_buffer_pool_instances - 8`.
We also found out that there were a lot of requests on the wp-cron.php (since we are using wordpress) which was locking the `wp_options` table and database connections were increasing drastically and halt the system too.
We blocked access to wp-cron.php for now in .htaccess and increased the RDS type to t2.large and system seems to be stable.

Comment: @OmarTanti - The documentation _hints_ that `.._instances` should be no more than 1 per GB of `.._size`; that is "2".  (I suspect the value does not matter much, other than 8G would be terrible.)

Comment: What is `wp_cron` doing?  Perhaps we should research that?  It is not clear that a bigger VM will help.  Could it be that it is reissuing a job before the previous copy is finished?  That is disasterous for any cron-like system.

Comment: Unfortunately `wp_cron` is not handled only by myself, 3rd party plugins also append their cronjobs to it. One of the main cron that I developed is to send 2,000 emails every 3 minutes via SES. Yes sometime there is a scenario that this cron overlaps but I added a locking functionality, in order to prevent same e-mails from being sent as duplicates and only a maximum of 2 instances of this cron can be executed simultaneously.  Now that I blocked any http requests to the `wp-cron.php` and changed the RDS to t2.large the system is quite stable and I did not have any issues yet (fingers crossed)

Comment: Another issue that I noticed was that due to the large amount of emails being sent, the table that kept record of all the emails sent was getting very large, in fact we had around 21 million records in 3 months.  I created an archiver and only kept latest emails sent in active table in order to improve query performance made on the referenced table.

Comment: What are these emails about?

Comment: Notifications about news posts created in a blog according to user preferences. But it does not make any difference right?

Comment: @OmarTanti - I don't want to help a spammer.  I moved my cron comments into my Answer.

Comment: No don't worry I am not a spammer.  Thanks a lot for your comments and suggestions. I will look into your suggestion and see how can I update my script.